# Passing a variable from Controller to View

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to pass an array from a Controller to a view like so:

Controller

```
public function newUser()
    {
        $company = Company::all();
        $list = array();
        foreach ($company as $companies)
        {
            $list[] = '<option value="'.$companies->id.'">'. $companies->name.'</option>';
        }

        return view('auth.register')->with($list);
    }
```

View

```
<select class="form-control" name="company">
    {{$list}}
</select>
```

Which keeps resulting in `Undefined variable: list`

I've also tried `return view('auth.register')->with('companies', $list);` Which results in `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

I am not using the form builders, I have created all the HTML myself.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by doing this.

Controller

```
 public function newUser()
    {
        $company = Company::all();
        $list = array();
        foreach ($company as $companies)
        {
            $list[$companies->id] = $companies->name;
        }

        return view('auth.register')->with('list', $list);
    }
```

View

```
<select class="form-control" name="company">
    @foreach($list as $key=> $value)
        <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be very easy by doing this:

**Controller:**

```
public function newUser()
{
    $companies = Company::lists('name', 'id');

    return view('auth.register', compact('companies'));
}
```

**View:**

```
{!! Form::select('company', $companies, null) !!}
```

Very clean, very simple.